# Bootstrap 3 grid, set 1 column size for all displays

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, gridview, size

In bootstrap v3, the column sizes are declared for different screen sizes..

```
<div class='container'>
    <div class='row'>
        <div class='col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-sm-6'>
```

I often find myself just needing 1 size for all display types.. and i thought this would be something like

```
        <div class='col-6'>
```

where no matter what display size the user is on, just keep the width of the column 6/12 of the grid system..  but this doesn't seem to work. What am I missing?

Comment: Your second question should be made into a new question instead of appended here (I now edited it out)

Answer (score 31):

The correct answer for *those* sizes is `<div class='col-sm-6'>`. This will apply to `sm` and everything larger than it.

However, there is a fourth size - `xs` - so using `<div class='col-xs-6'>` would apply to every possible size.

Comment: Now it is just `col-*` in bootstrap 4

Comment: @thelonglqd - Oh, that's great! Much clearer syntax.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tested this so it may be wrong. I remember having an issue with `col-lg-8` working but when the screen got to medium it all changed. Changing the class to `col-md-8` then worked for both.

Using that logic, try setting the class to the smallest you want and see it it inherits upwards.

Answer (score 0):

Have you try just: `<div class="col-md-6">`? Because I think there's not a class col-6 in bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

The prefix xs/sm/md/lg are at wich breakpoints the element snaps to full width.
You can see the breakpoints here: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

```
/* Extra small devices (phones, less than 768px) */
/* No media query since this is the default in Bootstrap */

/* Small devices (tablets, 768px and up) */
@media (min-width: @screen-sm-min) { ... }

/* Medium devices (desktops, 992px and up) */
@media (min-width: @screen-md-min) { ... }

/* Large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up) */
@media (min-width: @screen-lg-min) { ... }
```

So you should be able to use col-xm-6, as it has no breakpoint, or you could make your own class which has 50% width.